# Need to add two icon in same cell in lightning datatable lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

**As seen in the screenshot below I need to add arrow down utility icon next to up arrow. How to do it within the same cell? And also I need to align it to the right of the cell**

[image]

```
 clauseColumns = [
    {label : 'Selected Clauses', fieldName : 'headingName',
     cellAttributes:{ iconName: 'utility:up', Name: 'Up', alignment: 'Right'}},
  ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add only one icon in one cell at a time. You need to extend the standard lightning datatable by adding the custom data type. Check the **Creating Custom Data Types** section from [this document](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation).

Also, you can set the icon position to `left` or `right` using the `iconPosition` cell attribute in case you need only a single icon.

Comment: Here's an updated link to documentation on creating custom data types: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/data-table-custom-types